# Populate Pinterest Pin It Button with PHP

Tags: php, url, pinterest

I'm trying to be able to use the Pin It button but it does not automatically get the URL and image from the page. How can I populate the button dynamically with PHP?

Kind of like this [example](http://www.briangardner.com/pinterest-pin-it-button/), but **without** using the Genesis framework.

Answer (score 5):

I also was looking to build a dynamically populated Pinterest button, so I put this one together.  It makes use of the [simpleHTMLDom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to grab the first image on the page (for the image) and the first paragraph on the page (for the description).  These selectors can be modified to grab the correct image/text.  See the [simpleHTMLDom documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) for more info.

```
<?php
// Include our dom parser
include('simple_html_dom.php');

// Get the current page URL
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}

$thispage = curPageURL();

// Grab our data
$html = file_get_html($thispage);
$imgtag = $html->find('img', 0)->src;
$desc = $html->find('p', 0)->plaintext;

// Build the URL
$pinURL = 'http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=' . $thispage . '&media=' . $imgtag . '&description=' . $desc . '';

$html->clear(); 
unset($html);
?>
```

**Now we simply echo that new URL in the button link.**

```
<a href="<?php echo $pinURL ?>" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">Pin It</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

Comment: I built something like this using simpleHTMLDom and SimplePie when I built my news aggregators. The most popular of which can be seen here: http://news.muschamp.ca You need to scroll to the bottom to see the Pin It button created with PHP. It will be nice when Pinterest has an API because right now you can use jQuery to dynamically add Pin It buttons and they have RSS feeds and I've built stuff out of those, but a full API would be nice...

Answer (score 1):

This is the code created from Pinterest for the Pin It button.

Notice the inclusion of the php tags.  Put your own php code in there to populate the url, media, and description parameters. Done.

`<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo url_php_function(); ?>&media=<?php echo media_php_function(); ?>&description=<?php echo description_php_function(); ?>" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">Pin It</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at http://pinterest.com/about/goodies/ it appears they are encoding the URL or at least replacing something like '://' with '%3A%2F%2F' yet neither example above follows this pattern or is using urlencode.

I guess some trial and error is in order for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of code from the feature method in the news aggregator. Posts that are featured get a Pin It button if I can find an image with simpleHTMLDom.

```
            // Pinterest
        /*
        Pinterest requires two bits of code, something like this:
        <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.muschamp.ca%2F&media=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.muschamp.ca%2Fimage.jpg&description=whatever" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal"><img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" /></a>
        Where you want the button ie here, and 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
        directly after the body tag just like Facebook's new style button 
        */
        // I definitely miss how I did things in my previous code base, if there is no image should not be able to pin...
        if(($image != NULL) && ( ! strpos($image->src, '+')) && ( ! strpos($image->src, '%'))
            && (preg_match('|^http?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $image->src)))
        {
            // If I don't display a valid image, no sense in showing a Pin It button 
            $html .= '<li>'; // Opening <li>
            // May want a more elaborate description...
            $html .= '<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=' . $item->get_permalink() . '&media=' . $image->src . '&description=' . $item->get_title() . '" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal"><img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" /></a></li>';
        }
```

The elaborate if proved necessary in testing as certain valid URLs might not be accepted as valid by Pinterest's JavaScript at least that was something I discovered in testing. It appears the '%' and '+' character are particularly troublesome. Pinterest will not let you pin small images or even really large images, but since I also used PHP to resize the images in my news aggregator I don't test for that here, but it is something to keep in mine when adding Pinterest to your application.